# How to increase height of tab indicator

Tags: android

I have created 3 tabs .
But when i switch between tabs the height of tab indicator is very small,it comes like a thin line over tabs.I have not seen any post that gives me solution of this problem.All of them are about how to change the colour of tab indicator.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    try {

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        Log.d("In Tab Activity", bar.toString());
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Contacts");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab1);




        Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Messages");
        tab2.setCustomView(TabUtils.renderTabView(this, R.string.tab_invitations, R.drawable.ic_add_alert_black_24dp, 5));
        tab2.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab2);


        Tab tab3 = bar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("History");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);
        bar.addTab(tab3);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webPage);
        jSInterface = new AndroidJSInterface(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jSInterface, "AndroidJSInterface");

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HybridPage2.html", null);

        /*
         * Fragment main = new MainFragment(); FragmentTransaction ft =
         * getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         * ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, main);
         * ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
         * ft.addToBackStack(null); ft.commit();
         */
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception is", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code or an image or something?

Comment: Show the code of your tab bar implementation

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Which theme are you using? i.e your theme for activity or for the full application mentioned in styles.xml?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score 6):

you can specify the tab indicator height by `app:tabIndicatorHeight=".."` in your xml file under TabLayout.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, works as expected for the problem asked

Answer (score -1):

Use New design library and refer following code.You can change TabLayout width to change height of TAB.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tab_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I dont want to change height of Tab. I want to change height of TAB INDICATOR which comes when we click on tabs.